# JQueryEditor error python

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error from attempting to run my django app on salesforce cloud9. It is giving me a JQueryEditor, error even though I've installed django-redactor. Anything else I should install?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redactor/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from redactor.widgets import JQueryEditor
ImportError: cannot import name 'JQueryEditor'
```

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: django version 1.11.3

Comment: the django-redactor you are using is supported till 1.4 and has not been updated after that